# How can i get my output to read my binary number in reverse?

Tags: java

To begin with i want to input any number and have the output of that number in binary. But, my problem is that whenever i enter my number it is read backwards.

For example:

```
         input: 14
         binary number:0111
```

What i want is

```
         input: 14
         binary number:1110
```

Here is my code:

```
package poro;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Poro {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int z;
        int a;
        String x = "";
        System.out.print("input:");
        z = s.nextInt();
        while(z > 0)
        {
            a = z % 2;
            if(a == 1)

            {

            }
            x = x + "" + a;
            z = z / 2;

        }
        System.out.println("Binary number:"+x);

    }

}}
```

Comment: Put the new digits on the left instead of the right?

Comment: Replace this  **x = x + "" + a;** with this  **x = a + "" + x;**

Answer (score 0):

Each binary digit you get you append it at the end of the result string by `x = x + "" + a;`.  
If you append it at the start you will get the right result, so do: 
`x = a + x;`

Answer (score 0):

```
x = x + "" + a;
```

Since this appends the new digit, the MSB will always be on the right of the output. You'd want to prepend the new digit:

```
x = a + x;
```

Alternatively,

```
x = Integer.toBinaryString(z);
```

to do this all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You could prepend the digits you calculate instead of appending them:

```
x = a + "" + x;
```

It would be easier, though, to define `x` as a `StringBuilder`, and then just call

```
x.insert(0, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)'s class [`reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse--) method on the String:

`System.out.println("Binary number:" + new StringBuilder(x).reverse().toString());`

```
input:14
Binary number:1110
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good hint and this is how I did it without any added imports.

You're going to need something called a `for` loop.
This is like the `while` loop you have but has a more control on how to change values inside of an array that you're going to have later on in your class (guessing this because the level of the question).

You're going to need another `String` lets call `String backwords ="";`

A `for` loop that looks like this:

```
    for(int i=0; i<=x.length()-1; i++){
        //code to make backwords
    }
    System.out.println("backwords text : " + backwords);
```

This loop is setup to loop as long as long as the `String` x is.
All you would need to do is get the `substring` of a value you want and add it on to the `backwords`value that we made before.

So if we have a `String` like chicken and i want to get the 'k' in chicken
I'm going to want to do a `substring` on the `String` that holds the value chicken like this:

```
String chi = "chicken";
String getK = chi.substring(4,5);
System.out.println(getK);
```

If we then use your x with this example we can then build our new backwards value.
The only trick is that we will need to add this on to our backwards `String` until we hit the end of our loop.